# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in E:\xampp\htdocs\announcements\announcement.php on line 143

Tags: php, debugging, parsing

I get this error message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   $end in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\announcements\announcement.php
>   on line 143

Line 143 is the last line of the PHP file.
When I comment out

```
$htmlcode=<<<eod
<div>$question</div>
<div>$option1  $option2  $option3  $option4</div><br/>
eod;    
echo $htmlcode;
```

The error is gone.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out what after your `eod;`, you had some whitespaces there.

Remove the whitespaces and it will work fine.

Tested:

```
<?php
$htmlcode=<<<eod
<div>$question</div>
<div>$option1  $option2  $option3  $option4</div><br/>
eod;
echo $htmlcode;
?>
```

Comment: Cool.Right on target! Genius.

Comment: nothing much, just ran the code and tried out different ways to see what's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have spaces after `eod;`

As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> It is very important to note that the
>   line with the closing identifier must
>   contain no other characters, except
>   possibly  a semicolon (;). That means
>   especially that the identifier may not
>   be indented, and there may not be any
>   spaces or tabs before or after the
>   semicolon. It's also important to
>   realize that the first character
>   before the closing identifier must be
>   a newline as defined by the local
>   operating system. This is \n on UNIX
>   systems, including Mac OS X. The
>   closing delimiter (possibly followed
>   by a semicolon) must also be followed
>   by a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the variable names inside your `heredoc` block with `{` and `}` like so:

```
$htmlcode=<<<eod
<div>{$question}</div>
<div>{$option1}  {$option2}  {$option3}  {$option4}</div><br/>
eod;
echo $htmlcode;
```

The problem is that PHP chokes on the fact that you have no whitespace separating your `$question` and `$option4` variables from the opening `<` for your closing `div` tags.

Also, ensure that there's **no** whitespace after the semicolon following your `eod` delimiter. The only thing allowed on that line is your delimiter and a semicolon if necessary.

Comment: Actually, that's not really the case. Have you tried the code?

Comment: Ehm, i mean about the variables. The part about whitespace is true.

Comment: Not directly. But personal experience with PHP has led me down the path of debugging problems like this for hours upon hours.

Comment: Perhaps it's not such bad advice after all.